# how can i get preapproval key back in my return url of preapproval serivce call

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using adaptive payment in PayPal can i get preapproval key  back in my return URL of preapproval service call .

> AdaptivePaymentsService service = new AdaptivePaymentsService(
>                 configurationMap);      PreapprovalResponse resp = service.preapproval(req);

Answer (score 0):

The Preapproval Key will be returned in the Preapproval response when you make the API call, so you won't be able to make it part of the ReturnURL, but you can use session data or temporary database data to make it available to your app once returned to your ReturnURL.